# Exclude taxonomy term from list of current taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query

I am trying to display a list of custom taxonomy terms for the current page, but do not know how to filter out specific terms. My code is below. How do I exclude certain taxonomy terms? I'm still learning, so any help is appreciated.

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'service' );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    $term_link = get_term_link( $term ); ?>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <li><h6><a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h6></li>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you want to filter it at *database level*, then you would want to use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) - *but unlike `get_the_terms()`, the results are not cached* - and use the `exclude` arg to set the term IDs you want to be excluded. Otherwise, then you could achieve the same results (at PHP level) with something like `if ( in_array( $term->term_id, array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) ) { continue; }` right after the `foreach` line in your code.

Comment: I went with the if... else statements and it worked. Thanks!